# RegExp Word Boundaries

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a keyword surrounded by word boundaries, start or end of line, or dot.

```
Pattern.compile("[\\.|\b]v2[\b]").matcher("CREATE VIEW ${nameWithSchemaName} AS select id from testViewCreationOrder.v2").find()
```

Because the v2 is the end of the line, it returns false.
If I use

```
[\\.|\b]v2[\b|$]
```

it still return false, but
If I use

```
[\\.|\b]v2
```

returns true
What is wrong?

Comment: You cannot put anchors in a character set(square brackets). Use a conditional instead: `(\\.|\b)`

Comment: `[\\.|\b]` is a character class matching one of the characters `.`, `|` or `b`. You want an alternation `(\\.|\\b)` instead (note escaped \ before `b` as well).

Answer (score 1):

Your *main* problem is the use of `"\b"`, which is a backspace character, instead of `"\\b"`, which is a (literal) word boundary.

The other problem is putting a word boundary in a character class. A word boundary is not a character, so `"(\\.\\b)v2\\b"` instead of `"[\\.|\b]v2[\b]"` but you don't *need* the word boundary, because a dot creates one between the dot and a word character, so just:

```
"\\bv2\\b"
```

is what you want